# Wireless Access Point security with TEW-638APB

Tags: network, wifi

We have a large network that is private, with both eithernet and Wifi access.  We'd like to make another smaller network that is wireless, open, and possibly throttled, and not able to access our larger network with file and print servers.  Obviously, a good way to do this would to be to add a wireless router into the mix with DHCP enabled.  However we have an extra TEW-638APB and really appreciate the wireless range on these.  I'm wondering if it would be possible to set it up to do the job?

Comment: I'm going to say that this should probably be put on http://serverfault.com .  I believe you are wanting to set up Virtual Access Points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common configuration.

TRENDnet's kb has [this](http://www.trendnet.com/kb/kbp_viewquestion.asp?ToDo=view&questId=1695&catId=543) to say (not copied here for copyright reasons).  Basically, yes it is possible.  The AP can support up to 4 SSIDs that are on different VLANs.  Just set your routing to have your "guest" VLAN only route to the internet, and not to any of your internal segments.

Comment: How do you set your routing to only route to the internet?  
Thank you for your response! :)

Comment: I haven't used your particular model, but generally you would make routing rules based to drop packets destined for internal addresses.  Internal IPs are defined in RFC1918 (10/8, 172.16/12, and 192.168/16)